# fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: [-]

Tags: git, github-for-windows

in Git Bash (Windows XP) an error occurs permanent `[-] mapping_data_source::init error: file not found`. But earlier it wasn't cause of other errors. Now I'm trying to clone my repositorie and get errors:

```
$ git clone hello cloned_hello
[-] mapping_data_source::init error: file not found
Cloning into 'cloned_hello'...
fatal: protocol error: bad line lengt character: [-]
fatal: write error: Invalid argument
```

And without "_"

```
$ git clone hello clonedhello
[-] mapping_data_source::init error: file not found
Cloning into 'clonedhello'...
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: [-]
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Answer (score 0):

That can happen when you have a `.profile` or `.bashrc` in $HOME (in your Windows bash session) which does some echo (which is not silent)

To test that, check if the issue persists when you try and clone from a CMD session instead of a bash session (call `c:\path\to\PortableGit-2.6.3-64-bit\git-cmd.exe`  to open such a session)